# finding the shortest subsegment

Tags: string, algorithm

I wanted to know which alogrithm should i apply.

Their is a sentence given and a list to words. We have to find the first shortest sub segment that contains all the words in the list of words.

eg:

> Sentence - this is the best problem i have ever solved

List of words -

> is
>
> best
>
> this

The answer should be:

> this is the best

If there are many such sub segments then we have to print the one that contains the smallest number of words and appears first in sentence.

Comment: Must be a popular homework problem or something like that. Possible duplicate of [Google search results: How to find the minimum window that contains all the search keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734313/google-search-results-how-to-find-the-minimum-window-that-contains-all-the-sear) also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954626/algorithm-to-find-the-smallest-snippet-from-searching-a-document

Answer (score 5):

Here is my approach to solve the above problem.

**1**. Take 2 pointers head and tail both point to 0

Now move the head pointer until the word pointed to by the head pointer is a valid keyword; now mark it as head.

**2**. Now move tail pointer until the sentence contains all the given keywords at least once; now mark it as tail.

And this is the first valid subsegment with all valid keywords and calculate it's length

**3**. Now check word frequency at head - if it is greater than 1 now move head pointer to a word in the sentence which is a valid keyword, as well as it contains frequency of word as 1.

**4**. Now check whether all keywords are there or not - if yes, calculate it's length and store it as min sub-segment.

**5**. If it does not contains all valid keywords now move tail pointer until all keywords are found and calculate its length like (tail-head+1); if it is greater than min one then ignore it.

**6**. Now continue this process until last keyword of given sentence

The complexity of the above approach is o(n).

For example let us take this sentance

`Hi this is a funny world this is a good experience with this world`

and i need to find 3 keywords

```
this
is
world
```

at first consider 2 hash tables namely required,obtained
now store all required keywords in required table.

now take head and tail as 0 now check hi is a valid keyword since it it not move head

now check for next keyword i.e this ,now this is a valid keyword so make a count of 1 and store this word position as head .so now head is 1

now move tail pointer so next keyword is "is" ,it is a valid one hence increment count
now similarly check for a,funny keywords since they are not valid ones hence move tail to world

now world is a valid one as well as count is 3  and tail is 4 whenever count == no of required keywords(in our case it is 3) that means our segment contains all valid keywords

now it's length is (4-1+1)=4

now check frequency of word at head it is one hence if we move this head pointer then we won't get a valid segment

so now move tail pointer to next word this now update frequency of this to 2 from 1 and counter becomes 4

so now we can move our head pointer now move to a keyword is now update counter as 3 because our segment won't contain this at this moment because we have shifted the head pointer from this keyword

now again count is 3 hence calculate it's length again it is 4

so check freq of head keyword is it is 1 hence move tail pointer to next keyword is now is keyword freq is more than 1 hence now move head pointer until we get a valid keyword with freq as 1 now obtained keyword is world and head position is 5 and tail position is 7 
and counter is 3 so calculate length as 7-5+1 which is 3 hence this is a min length that we found till now

now move tail until keyword freq at head is more than 1 now finally our tail become 13

now move head from 5 to 6 calculate it's length ,and it becomes 13-6+1 which is 8 so ignore it

now further we cannot move our tail hence print the words from min_head to min_tail as final result

in our case the answer is

world this is

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following simple approach -

Make a dictionary mapping(enumeration) for each word in the sentence. Like -

> this[1] is[2] the[3] best[4] problem[5] i[6] have[7] ever[8] solved[9]

Assuming all are distinct words in the sentence.

Now, taking one word at a time and keeping the record of max and min value of that word as key. In this case it would be 4 and 1, resp.
Return the string within the limits.

Comment: if the words are not distinct in sentence?