# Finding the smallest window

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Given two arrays `A[n]` and `B[m]`, how can I find the smallest window in `A` that contains all the elements of `B`.

I am trying to solve this problem in O(n) time but I am having problem doing it. Is there any well know algorithm or procedure for solving it.

Comment: what is "window" in this context?

Comment: ex: A= {1,3,2,4,5,6,1,2} B= {1,2} so smallest window is from index 6 to 7.

Comment: Does the window have to contain all elements of B? Is the order important? Or, in your example, do positions 2..6 also constitute a window containing B?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google search results: How to find the minimum window that contains all the search keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734313/google-search-results-how-to-find-the-minimum-window-that-contains-all-the-searc) While it is formulated a bit differently, it is exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

countLet's call window 'minimal' if it can't be reduced. I.e., after increasing its left border or decreasing its right border it's no longer valid window (doesn't contain all elements from B). There three in your example: [0, 2], [2, 6], [6, 7]

Let's assume say that you already found leftmost minimal window [left, right]. ([0, 2] in your example) Now we'll just slide it to the right.

```
// count[x] tells how many times number 'x'
// happens between 'left' and 'right' in 'A'
while (right < N - 1) {
    // move right border by 1
    ++right;
    if (A[right] is in B) {
        ++count[A[right]];
    }

    // check if we can move left border now
    while (count[A[left]] > 1) {
        --count[A[left]];
        ++left;
    }

    // check if current window is optimal
    if (right - left + 1 < currentMin) {
        currentMin = right - left + 1;
    }
}
```

This sliding works because different 'minimal' windows can't contain one another.

Comment: Essentially the same as mine, except you haven't specified how `count` works, while mine is harder to follow.

Comment: Weeeell, it can be just an array, if numbers in B aren't too big :) but you're right, it's the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much Artelius and Nikita

Answer (score 4):

If `m > n`, `A` cannot contain all the elements of `B` (and hence we have an `O(1)` solution).

Otherwise:

- Create a hash table mapping elements of `B` to the sequence {0..m-1} (this is `O(n)` since `m <= n`) .
- Create an array `C[m]` to count occurences of the members of `B` (initialise to 0) in the current window.
- Create a variable `z` to count the the number of 0 elements of `C` (initialise to `m`).
- Create variables `s` and `e` to denote the start and end of the current window
- while `e < n`:

  - If `z` is nonzero, increment `e` and update `C` and `z`. `O(1)`
  - else consider this window as a possible solution (i.e. if it's the min so far, store it), then increment `s` and update `C` and `z`. `O(1)`

The while loop can be shown to have no more than `2n` iterations. So the whole thing is `O(n)`, I think.